# sql get row interval of 5 minute between two date

Tags: sql, database-administration, schedule

Is there a way to get minute interval like 5,10 or 15 min between to date? Here's an example:

#### I have two date:

```
2016-07-25 14:00:00.000 || 2016-07-25 18:00:00.000
```

and I want a function who can return me a set of row depending which parameter interval i give to return me that:

#### when interval parameter is 5 min:

```
2016-07-25 14:05:00.000
2016-07-25 14:10:00.000
2016-07-25 14:15:00.000
2016-07-25 14:20:00.000
2016-07-25 14:25:00.000
2016-07-25 ...
2016-07-25 18:00:00.000
```

#### when interval parameter is 10 min:

```
2016-07-25 14:10:00.000
2016-07-25 14:20:00.000
2016-07-25 14:30:00.000
2016-07-25 14:40:00.000
2016-07-25 14:50:00.000
2016-07-25 ...
2016-07-25 18:00:00.000
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  You'll need a table like a [time dimension table](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/642912/Create-Populate-Time-Dimension-with-Hourplus-Va) that includes the intervals you're interested in.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[Demo Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/518534/interval-queries)</kbd>

Using Recursive CTE,this can be plugged into a function..

```
declare @start datetime='2016-07-25 14:00:00.000'
declare @end datetime='2016-07-25 18:00:00.000'

;With cte(starttime,endtime)
as
(
select @start,@end
union all
select dateadd(minute,5,starttime),endtime
from cte c
where datediff(minute,c.starttime,c.endtime)>0
)
select * from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, i think what you are looking for is this script:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf1 (@interval int, @start datetime, @end datetime)
RETURNS @out TABLE (date1 datetime)
BEGIN
--declare @start datetime='2016-07-25 14:00:00.000', @end datetime='2016-07-25 18:00:00.000', @curr datetime

set @curr = @start
while (dateadd(mi,@interval,@curr)<=@end)
begin
    set @curr = dateadd(mi,@interval,@curr)
    insert into @out
    select @curr
end
return;
END

select *
from dbo.udf1(10,'2016-07-25 14:00:00.000','2016-07-25 18:00:00.000')
```

Comment: Good script. I suggest let start , end as parameters

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Numbers/Tally table, but I use a UDF to create Dynamic Date Ranges

```
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-07-25 14:00:00.000','2016-07-25 18:00:00.000','MI',5)
```

Notice not only is the start/end a parameter, but also the DatePart and Increment

Returns

```
RetVal
2016-07-25 14:00:00.000
2016-07-25 14:05:00.000
2016-07-25 14:10:00.000
...
2016-07-25 17:55:00.000
2016-07-25 18:00:00.000
```

> The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date] (@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime,@DatePart varchar(10),@Incr int)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal datetime)

As
Begin
    With DateTable As (
        Select DateFrom = @DateFrom
        Union All
        Select Case @DatePart
               When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               End
        From DateTable DF
        Where DF.DateFrom < @DateTo
    )

    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal) Select DateFrom From DateTable option (maxrecursion 32767)

    Return
End

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','DD',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-31','MI',15) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-02','SS',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers I found out how with that

```
 create function fn_daterange
   (
   @MinDate as datetime,
   @MaxDate as datetime,
   @intval  as datetime
   )
returns table
--**************************************************************************
-- Procedure: fn_daterange()
--    Author: Ron Savage
--      Date: 12/16/2008
--
-- Description:
-- This function takes a starting and ending date and an interval, then
-- returns a table of all the dates in that range at the specified interval.
--
-- Change History:
-- Date        Init. Description
-- 12/16/2008  RS    Created.
-- **************************************************************************
as
return
   WITH times (startdate, enddate, intervl) AS
      (
      SELECT @MinDate as startdate, @MinDate + @intval as enddate, @intval as intervl
         UNION ALL
      SELECT startdate + intervl as startdate, enddate + intervl as enddate, intervl as intervl
      FROM times
      WHERE startdate + intervl <= @MaxDate
      )
   select startdate, enddate from times;

go
```